# How to get data from HttpServletResponse from ajax form

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have "first.jsp" with a form with hidden input values and method pointing another jsp.

```
<form id="popupForm" name="popupForm" action="<%= cqRequest.externalizeHref(handle) %>" method="post"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="method" value="second"/> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="qualident" value="<%= qualident %>"/> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="val1" value="<%=val1%>"/> 
...
</form>
```

After Submiting the form the java code in the "second.jsp" runs and it calls a web service that has the return Integer value, but the javascript part of the file is not run.

```
 Integer retVal = method(...);
```

How can I get that integer value in the first jsp?
- I tried with writing it into the respone with Printwriter, and set the form datatype to 'text'/'json' but then I cannot substring/split or do anything with the response text, it always stays the original after every operation.

```
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 
        pw.print("#_#"); 
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
        obj.put("retVal", <%=retVal%>); 
        pw.print(obj); 
        pw.flush(); 
        pw.close();
```

- I tried to do with setting session attribrute or sessionstorage but the javascript/jquery does not run in the second.jsp on the form submit.

What is the way to get the variable in the first jsp to be able to check the return value of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may work like this:

1. Submit your form on `first.jsp` page
2. Again, `second.jsp` will receive the request and calls the web service to get integer value.
3. Set the attributes in request object
4. Use the `RequestDispatcher`  to go back to `first.jsp` page and fetch your attributes from `HttpServletRequest` object.